# Service Django is not running container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I try to debug an app inside of the container and I need to run django to run tests I do that by:

```
docker-compose exec django bash
```

But as a result I get:

```
service "django" is not running container #1
```

I don't really understand what this response means and I didn't find any information regarding that. This issue prevents me from being able to debug a code inside of the container with the database up and running.

Comment: The error means exactly what it says: you can only use `docker-compose exec` against containers that have actually started up.  Do you need to run `docker-compose up -d` first?  If the container isn't starting up, can you `docker-compose run` the debugging shell in a temporary container?  Can you debug your application on the host but pointing at the containerized database?

Answer (score 0):

if docker ps show a container name "django"
then run if you want to get bash prompt in:

```
docker exec -ti django bin/bash
```

if bash not available you can try bin/sh

if container isn't running you can't go in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check docker-compose.yaml

You wrote it:

```
docker-compose exec django bash
```

Try this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web: # check
    container_name: django
```

```
docker-compose exec -it web /bin/bash
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).